# Select Top N elements nested objects

Tags: c#

I want to select top N related products using `GetTopRelatedProducts` method.

```
class Product
    {
        public string Name;
        public double Rating;
        public List<Product> RelatedProducts;

        public List<Product> GetTopRelatedProducts(int N)
        {
            var relatedSet = new HashSet<Product>();
            var relatedListQueue = new Queue<List<Product>>();
            if (RelatedProducts != null && RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
                relatedListQueue.Enqueue(RelatedProducts);
            while (relatedListQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                var relatedList = relatedListQueue.Dequeue();
                foreach (var product in relatedList)
                {
                    if (product != this && relatedSet.Add(product) && product.RelatedProducts != null && product.RelatedProducts.Count > 0)
                        relatedListQueue.Enqueue(product.RelatedProducts);
                }
            }
            // use intersect to re-order by occurence: first element added to HashSet will be displayed first
            return relatedSet.Intersect(relatedSet.OrderByDescending(x => x.Rating).Take(N)).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestion how to improve the code?

Comment: When is a product `related`?

Comment: Product relations are saved in the database. But in the memory, a product `B` is related to product `A`, only if it belongs to `RelatedProducts` list of product `A`. This relation could be mutual.

Comment: Did you tried recursive?